# What is the original language for Revelation 13:16-17?

Tags: revelation

Does the original language in Revelation 13:16-17 mean 'on the right hand or forehead' or 'in the right hand or   forehead'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant section of Rev 13:16 is:

> **ἐπὶ** τῆς χειρὸς αὐτῶν τῆς δεξιᾶς ἢ **ἐπὶ** τὸ μέτωπον αὐτῶν = on/upon the right hand of them or on/upon the forehead of them

The Greek preposition ἐπὶ (epi) in this context definitely means "on or upon" because it is used in conjunction with a genitive noun, χειρὸς ("hand") and accusative μέτωπον ("forehead") so must be rendered equivalent to "of the place on which", or simply "on"; ie, answering the question "where?" (See BDAG)

Comment: Does the original Greek say “forehead or hand”, or “forehead and hand”, please?

Comment: @Constantthin - I have given my very literal translation above.  It says both.

Comment: So it is “or” then. I thought maybe the original Greek word could have been “and”. Or, that that word could be translated to either of the two. Sorry for bringing it up, because it is a completely new question, although somewhat related.

Comment: @Constantthin - PLEASE read my answer.  All these things are in my answer.  The translation is literally, (as quoted above) "on/upon the right hand of them or on/upon the forehead of them"

Comment: Your answer concerns the Greek word “epi”, right. My problem concerns the word preceding that word. Namely the word “e”.  Mist, if not all, Bible versions translates this word: “or”.  And Bible Hub has the word “e” to be “or”, “rather”, “than”, etc. But at one place the word “and” is mentioned.

Comment: Thus, the sentence might say: “force people to take the mark on their forehead and their hand”, instead of “force people to take the mark on their forehead or their hand”. I the first example people would have  two marks on their body. One on the rut forehead and one on their  hand. But, only if this version is possible, which I am pondering over.

Comment: Haweis New Testament translation is the only version that has “and”, which could imply two marks on the same body: “And he causeth all the small and the great, the rich and the poor, the freemen and the slaves, to receive a brand upon their right hand, and upon their foreheads”

Comment: @Constantthin - I answered the question asked which was primarily about "epi".  If you want to ask another question about the Greek particle ἢ then you should do so.  Second, the text says nothing about "forcing" anyone - the verb used is to "give" (δῶσιν) the mark.

Comment: “Give”. Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: I was confused because the King James Bible says '...In their right hand or in their forehead', and other translations read '...on their right hand or on their forehead'.